# jquery each loop only looping once and if using else code stops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two problems with the following javascript and jquery code.
The jquery each loop only iterates once, it gets the first element with the right ID does what it needs to do and stops.

The second problems is that when I use the else in the code the one inside the each function, it doesn't even tries the next if, it just exits there.
I'm probably doing something fundamental wrong, but from the jquery each function and what I'd expect from an else, I don't see it.

Javascript code:

```
var $checkVal;
var $checkFailed;

$("#compliance").live("keypress", function (e) {

 if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    var checkID = $(this).parents('td').next().attr('id');
    var checkVal = $(this).val();
    $('#' + checkID).each(function () {
        var cellVal = $(this).text();
        if (checkVal == cellVal) {
            $(this).removeClass("compFail").addClass("compOk");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("compOk").addClass("compFail");
            var checkFailed = True;
        }
    });
    if (checkFailed == 'True') {
        (this).addClass("compFail");
    } else {
        (this).addClass("compOk");
    }
 }
});
```

How could I get the each loop to iterate through all instances of each element with the id assigned to the variable checkID, and get the code to continue after the else, so it can do the last if?

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one instance of an ID on a page. Or did I misunderstand that.

Comment: `$('#' + checkID)` will only return a single element, since you are using the ID-selector and an ID is meant to be unique to a single element. Therefor running `.each()` on the returned set of elements is pointless, since it will always be a single element.

Comment: Would need to see some html for your first problem. For problem two, notice that you declare a variable inside the .each, and then attempt to use it outside.

Comment: first problem understood, thanks all :-)

Comment: Mike C, for the second problem, I declare the variable in the second line, outside all the functions. Should it work like that as the other variable does?

Comment: If your intent is to use it as a global variable, remove the var from in front so that you stop declaring it as a local variable, and use the global variable. It may still work, but it threw me off (having the var), and your intent will be more clear if you remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to illustrate what I'm talking about in my comment, so that you do not remove the wrong var:

```
var checkVal;
var checkFailed;

$("#compliance").live("keypress", function (e) {

 if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    var checkID = $(this).parents('td').next().attr('id');
    //HERE is the first edit
    checkVal = $(this).val();
    $('#' + checkID).each(function () {
        var cellVal = $(this).text();
        if (checkVal == cellVal) {
            $(this).removeClass("compFail").addClass("compOk");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("compOk").addClass("compFail");
            //HERE is the second
            checkFailed = True;
        }
    });
    if (checkFailed == 'True') {
        (this).addClass("compFail");
    } else {
        (this).addClass("compOk");
    }
 }
});
```

Normally, the way you have it would cause a compile-time error (in a typed language like C#) for redeclaring a variable. Here, it's not clear to me if it will be used as a local variable (ignoring your global variable) or if javascript will combine them and consider them the same. Either way, you should use it as I have shown so that your intent is more clear.

EDIT: I have removed the $ from your variables (var $checkVal) as on jsFiddle it was causing issues. SO if you do not need those $'s, then remove them. Also, note that testing on jsFiddle indicates that you do not need to change your code (other than possibly removing the $ from your declaration) as javascript appears to consider them the same variable, despite the redeclaration, which I find a bit suprising tbh.

Comment: Hi Mike,thanks a lot for the explanation, I understand it now. I've just declared the variables twice instead of declaring it once and assigning a value later.

Answer (score 4):

An `id` should appear on a page **only once**. If you want to have multiple elements with same id, then use a `class`, not an `id`.

Your `each` loop iter only once because you are selecting by `id` thus you are selecting only one element in the page. If you change you elements to a `class` it should work like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> The jquery each loop only iterates once, it gets the first element
>   with the right ID does what it needs to do and stops.

Yes, this is absolutely right for the code you're using:

```
$('#' + checkID).each(function(){};)
```

ID attributes are unique. There must be only one element with a given ID in the DOM. Your selector can match only one element. You are iterating over a collection containing just 1 item.